# How well does Intel Graphics on Linux work vs Windows, for gaming and day-to-day use?

Tags: windows, intel-graphics, intel, playonlinux

I've always used nVidia cards on Linux and I'm planning to get a new laptop that has Intel I3 7100U with Intel graphics 620. I haven't used Intel drivers before, and I'm willing to play light games from Steam like Counter Strike, Go and things like that. Has anyone tried games with Intel graphics? How is it for day-to-day tasks like watching full videos?

Comment: Some games you intend to play may work fine with Intel Grpahics but CS:GO apparently not. Please check the system requirements: http://store.steampowered.com/app/730/?

Comment: This question might be closed as too broad looking at gaming criteria only. But OP also questions day-to-day graphics use on modern processors with embedded GPU's. Many first time Linux / Ubuntu users will be interested about this general issue. Based on second half of the question I think it should remain open.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to games and response time using Intel Hybrid Graphics. That's a personal call after reducing frame rates and resolution as required.

As far as Intel Hybrid graphics in general I have a five year old Intel Core I7 3630QM with integrated HD-4000 graphics and when only using Chrome (8 tabs) and Conky CPU utilization is about 5%.

When watching videos on external HDMI TV under same scenario on laptop CPU utlization jumps to about 10-13%. HTML5 live streaming on Youtube is a percent or two more demanding than Flashplayer or watching a movie downloaded.

I have tried every few months to setup nVidia to utilize the built in GeForce GT650M card without much luck, nor much passion to do so as Intel on board GPU has been great so far.

As far as gaming goes, every few months I'll boot Windows 8.1 and waste a few hours / days there.